# Dagger 2 - Injecting class to declared interface

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have a dependency on a class (User) in my ApiService. I have already a `provideUser` in my Component class. I'm trying to inject with same provideUser my User class to 2 fields. The problem is that one field is a class and the second is an interface like this:

```
@Inject
User user;

@Inject
UserFull userFull;
```

And component code:

```
package com.ltx.dagger2.components;
import com.ltx.dagger2.activities.MainActivity;
import com.ltx.dagger2.modules.BackendServiceModule;
import com.ltx.dagger2.modules.UserModule;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import dagger.Component;


@Singleton
@Component(modules = {UserModule.class, ... other stuff})
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity activity);
}
```

Other elements of the equation:

```
public class User implements UserFull {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;

    public User(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public String getFullName() {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
}

public interface UserFull {

    String getFullName();
}
```

And module code:

```
package com.ltx.dagger2.modules;import com.ltx.dagger2.models.User; import com.ltx.dagger2.models.UserFull; import javax.inject.Singleton;import dagger.Module; import dagger.Provides;

@Module
public class UserModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    User provideUser() {
        return new User("Hakuna","Matata");
    }
}
```

Can I force Dagger2 to provide the same User class to UserFull field or I always have to add specific `UserFull provideUserFull` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way of doing this would be making another method in your `@Module`, which will take `User` as an argument and return it as `UserFull`:

```
@Module
public class UserModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    User provideUser() {
        return new User("Hakuna","Matata");
    }

    @Provides
    UserFull provideUserFull(User user) {
        return user;
    }
}
```

The `User` argument will be fulfilled by `provideUser()` method.

There's no way for Dagger to guess by itself which implementation of `UserFull` it has to provide. This is why you have to specify this and add the second method.

Comment: Yeah, that's also my solution but I kinda hoped to find something more elegant. Now that I'm thinking it's probably difficult to be unambiguous when injecting implementation. But still, I'll keep question open for more ideas (if any) then I'll mark accepted answer. Multzam.